# transfer/send error cases

Tags: solidity, gas, security, error

I have a (noob) question on the usage of `transfer` and `send`. I have seen that `transfer` is equivalent to

```
 require(x.send(k));
```

When I use `send(`) I know that I have to check whether there was an error during the execution and then handle it like:

```
   if(!x.send(y)) {
    //...
   }
```

1) In case there is an error, do I have to write `revert()` inside the block? To be more specific, since send allows the usage of 2300 gas, in case changes are made inside the receiver contract fallback function, are they reverted automatically?

2) If I use `transfer()` I don't have to check for errors right? If something goes wrong all code executed is reverted and the remaining gas refunded(I think).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

*In my opinion*, only use `.send()` if you know what you're doing and you want to carry on without reverting your own contract or others in the chain of functions.

If you add a `revert()` after `if(!x.send(y)) {` then that will undo whatever else is in that `if` block and raise an error that will revert everything back to before the transaction was signed ... like a `.transfer()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

While @rob-hitchens said it all, I'm just gonna add some comments.

> 1. In case there is an error, do I have to write revert() inside the block? To be more specific, since send allows the usage of 2300 gas, in case changes are made inside the receiver contract fallback function, are they reverted automatically?

Yes, you have to handle revert manually in case you are using `send`. `send` only returns a boolean which depends on the `send` being successful or not. To understand `send` better, think of it as a subcall, where it either runs atomically or fails as a whole, and the output is just a boolean showing success/fail of the subcall.

> 2. If I use transfer() I don't have to check for errors right? If something goes wrong all code executed is reverted and the remaining gas refunded(I think).

Yes, you got it right. If `transfer` fails the whole call context fails and things are reverted to the start.

But you should know that usage of both `send` and `transfer` are not recommended anymore, it is better that you use `call` instead. To understand send, transfer, and call better, I highly recommend reading [this](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/).